# Unknown User - Can't find based on Id

Tags: apex, soql, exception, userrecordaccess

We have the following apex code in our trigger.

```
Id myId = UserInfo.getUserId();
User me = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Profile.Id, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Id=:myId];
```

This line sometimes throws below exception which I receive in an email. The weird part is that there is no user in the system with the ID 00540000005mdSZ.

> Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: 00540000005mdSZ/00D40000000MHk0
>
> AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

What could be the reason for this error then and from where does the User Id in the error comes from?

Comment: You should never assign a query to an object, use list instead. For your second problem, its quite possible that the user id is of different org. Try matching your org id.

Comment: I have already matched the Org Id; its from the same org where I am searching for the user.

Comment: Does the running user have view permission on the `User` object?

Comment: My problem is that I can't find who the running user is. The ID I receive in exception email is something I have not been able to find in Salesforce.

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217418/exception-email-alert-cites-a-userid-that-doesnt-exist-in-my-org/217424#217424

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code must be written in this way:

```
Id myId = UserInfo.getUserId();
List<User> me = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Profile.Id, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Id=:myId];

if(me.size()>0)
{
   // Do something 
}
else
{
  // show error message. Halt the process, throw exception
}
```

Above approach will never throw the error: `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

Regarding the Id you couldn't find. Apex email always reference the UserID and the Oranization Id joined by `/`.

So just search for the Organization having this ID `00D40000000MHk0` and then look for the user in Developer Console having the ID `00540000005mdSZ` in that organization.

Comment: I just never expected the query to throw the error since we are fetching the user id just above that. Regarding looking for the user, I have already done so. I have used workbench to query it, I have used pasted the ID in the url and it doesn't returns me anything.

Comment: you are correct. Since there are no chances of not getting the Id. But some times you don't have necessary permissions on user object and run into issues. Since you have done everything. Check for all community user, Site guest users etc. If all in vain, then log a case to Salesforce. @RajeshShah